# How to finish a setTimeout function when mouseenter on another function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout, mouseleave

At http://jsfiddle.net/builtbymay/Wge4n/4/, mouse over the Basecamp call-to-action button and then move your mouse to the left of your browser window. You will notice that the heading changes back after a delay of 1000ms. Nice! Now mouse over it again, but this time move your mouse over Highrise. Not nice!

I'm thinking I need to speed up the delay that occurred when mousing over the Basecamp button. clearTimeout didn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 1000;
    $('.products .bc').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('header').addClass('hidden');
        $('.bc:first').removeClass('hidden').css({
            'clear': 'both',
            'width': '829px',
            'height': '163px',
            'margin': '0 auto',
            'padding': '6px 0',
            'text-align': 'center',
            'font-family': '"CrimsonSemiBold", "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif',
        });
        // Added bc:first to prevent styles being added to other .bc classes.
        $('.bc:first h1, .bc:first p').css('padding', '18px 0 0');
        // Adjusting vertical layout so red arrow more closely matches location on 37signals.com.  
        $('.bc:last').css('box-shadow', '0 0 10px #333');
    });
    $('.products .bc').on('mouseleave', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('header').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.bc:first').addClass('hidden').removeAttr('style');
            $('.bc:last').removeAttr('style');
        }, delay);
    });
    $('.products .hr').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('header').addClass('hidden');
        $('.hr:first').removeClass('hidden').css({
            'clear': 'both',
            'width': '829px',
            'height': '163px',
            'margin': '0 auto',
            'padding': '6px 0',
            'text-align': 'center',
            'font-family': '"CrimsonSemiBold", "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif',
        });
        $('.hr:first h1, .hr:first p').css('padding', '18px 0 0');
        $('.hr:last').css('box-shadow', '0 0 10px #333');
        $('.right-arrow-b').removeClass('right-arrow-b').css({
            'left': '80px',
            'position': 'relative',
            'z-index': '1'
        });
    });
    $('.products .hr').on('mouseleave', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('header').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.hr:first').addClass('hidden').removeAttr('style');
            $('.hr:last').removeAttr('style');
            $('.right-arrow-b').addClass('right-arrow-b').removeAttr('style');
        }, delay);
    });
    $('.products .cf').on('mouseenter', function() {
        $('header').addClass('hidden');
        $('.cf:first').removeClass('hidden').css({
            'clear': 'both',
            'width': '829px',
            'height': '163px',
            'margin': '0 auto',
            'padding': '6px 0',
            'text-align': 'center',
            'font-family': '"CrimsonSemiBold", "Times New Roman", Georgia, serif',
        });
        $('.cf:first h1, .cf:first p').css('padding', '18px 0 0');
        $('.cf:last').css('box-shadow', '0 0 10px #333');
        $('.left-arrow').removeClass('left-arrow').css({
            'left': '150px',
            'position': 'relative',
            'z-index': '1'
        });
    });
    $('.products .cf').on('mouseleave', function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('header').removeClass('hidden');
            $('.cf:first').addClass('hidden').removeAttr('style');
            $('.cf:last').removeAttr('style');
            $('.left-arrow').addClass('left-arrow').removeAttr('style');
        }, delay);
    });
});
```

FYI: The CSS and HTML was borrowed from another classmate. My task was to get the behaviors to reflect those on 37signals.com, without editing any HTML and CSS in the process. There is a lot of css manipulation happening—just ignore it. My last task is to get the above issue resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it somewhere, but I do not see a clearTimeout() anywhere in the code you provided.

Comment: `var A = setTimeout(function() {............` and `clearTimeout(A);`

Comment: Maybe clearTimeout won't work with the way I have the functions set up. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wge4n/5/). I made a separate function to perform the functions of `mouseleave` event. On `mouseenter` of one button performs the function of `mouseleave` of other 2 buttons. In addition I keep an array of IDs of `setTimeout`. And in the previously mentioned function I also clear all the timers.

Comment: I like how the functions for the mouseleave event were separated. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Define a global variable wich holds the timer

```js
var globalTimer = null;
```

above the `$(document).ready(function() ...`, it's important that this var is not defined within a method.

Now assign the timeout to this var and check if its set and if it needs to be cleared in all your methods.

```js
if(gloabalTimer != null) window.clearTimeout(gloabalTimer);
globalTimer = window.setTimeout(function() {
    //Your actions
}), delay);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Merec. I still have a lot to learn. Thanks!